# Deploying windows 8 app on several devices without app store

Tags: windows-store-apps, sideloading

Is it possible to push windows 8 app directly to some not development-devices (without direct access to device)? For example, if one wants to install demo version of our app during the exhibition on devices of someone who intersted on our product.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the application deployment bypassing the Windows Store is called *sideloading*.

One basically has [two options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj657971.aspx) to perform sideloading:

1. `Windows 8 Pro`  and  `Windows Server 8`, if they are joined to a domain, are directly ready for side-loading.
2. `Windows 8` and `Windows 8 RT`, as well as the above-mentioned systems without domain, require the activation of a special `Sideloading key`, which can be purchased by enterprises only and usually available in 100 packs (priced at $3000 per pack, $30 per licence).

The installation of the app can be done either by using the application image and DISM or in runtime by `add-appxpackage` PowerShell CmdLet.

[Here](http://www.windowsblog.at/post/2013/02/06/Windows-8-Enterprise-Sideloading.aspx) is a good explanation of the whole process (in German).

Answer (score 1):

No, it would not be practical at an exhibition to provide direct loading of your application, bypassing the Windows Store. The Windows Store is there to provide a safe environment in which to download [certified applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694083.aspx).

It would be a far better experience if users could download from the Windows Store a trial version directly -- maybe you could provide free a wifi/network connection, and a bit.ly link or QR code of some sort to quickly get to the download for your application. :)

While it is possible to do side-loading ([walkthrough](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/jj874388.aspx)) in some circumstances, it was not intended to be used in this case. It's intended for Enterprise deployment and the walkthrough article has lots of details about the specific options and the costs associated if the destination machines/Windows isn't running Windows 8+ Enterprise edition.

One other option is that you can also deploy an application for testing purposes to another developer machine (which requires a Windows 8 developer license). It would be unusual for anyone but a Windows 8 application developer to have this activated (as you know, they expire after 30 days). This may be a violation of the licensing agreement though as it is expected that this is for development purposes only. It also involves powershell, so it would be a potentially awkward installation experience at an exhibition.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible dude...

Just developer unlock ur phone and deploy apps directly from PC.